# How to center my imageView inside another ImageView programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Hi this is my first post. thanks for helping.

I created a UIImageView and added a blur effect over it. Now i added another UIImageView as a subview of the blurred image view. I am trying to figure out how I can make its height and width proportional programmatically so that it will look good on all screen sizes

I figured out how to center it but cant get the size to look good.
I want the height to be a little smaller then the height of its superview and its a circle so the width would equal the height.

```
//create blurred profile picture
    //first create the uiimageview
    let blurProfilePic = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 64, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height/3.0))
    //assign it a value
    blurProfilePic.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
    //make sure it stays within the created bounds
    blurProfilePic.layer.masksToBounds = true
    //center the picture
    blurProfilePic.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center


    //create blur effect
    var visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)) as UIVisualEffectView
    visualEffectView.frame = blurProfilePic.bounds

    //add blur layer to blurProfilePic
    blurProfilePic.addSubview(visualEffectView)

    //create the real profile pic
    //arbitrary frame
    let profilePic = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 180, 180))
    //the 180,180 needs to be changed so that they are sized proportionally for all screens
    //center it inside the blurimage
    profilePic.center = CGPointMake(blurProfilePic.frame.size.width/2, blurProfilePic.frame.size.height/2)
    profilePic.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
    profilePic.layer.borderWidth = 5
    profilePic.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = profilePic.frame.size.width/2
    profilePic.clipsToBounds = true


    blurProfilePic.addSubview(profilePic)

    view.addSubview(blurProfilePic)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help you?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
        let blurProfilePic = UIImageView()
        let profilePic = UIImageView()

        override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
                blurProfilePic.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height / 3)

                let blurProfilePicBounds = blurProfilePic.bounds
                profilePic.frame.size = CGSize(width: blurProfilePicBounds.height, height: blurProfilePicBounds.height)
                profilePic.center = CGPointMake(blurProfilePicBounds.width / 2, blurProfilePicBounds.height / 2)
                profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = profilePic.frame.size.width / 2
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()

                //assign it a value
                blurProfilePic.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
                //make sure it stays within the created bounds
                blurProfilePic.layer.masksToBounds = true
                //center the picture
                blurProfilePic.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill

                //create blur effect
                var visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)) as UIVisualEffectView
                visualEffectView.frame = blurProfilePic.bounds
                visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleHeight
                //add blur layer to blurProfilePic
                blurProfilePic.addSubview(visualEffectView)

                profilePic.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
                profilePic.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
                profilePic.layer.borderWidth = 5
                profilePic.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
                profilePic.clipsToBounds = true

                blurProfilePic.addSubview(profilePic)

                view.addSubview(blurProfilePic)
        }
}
```

**Update:**

This is the snapshot when I set `profilePic.contentMode` and `blurProfilePic.conteMode` both to `.ScaleAspectFill`, it seems well

[image]

If I set `profilePic.contentMode` to `.ScaleAspectFit`, you can see the image is not resized to fill the circle.

[image]

Comment: unfortunately this does not solve the issue. If I run this in an iphone 4/4s the image is cut off. I want the image to be sized correctly for all iphones...its already centered for all iphone but I want the image to get bigger/shrink using the frame properties but I cant figure out how.

Comment: @JeremySh Sorry, I updated it again, please check it.

Comment: thank you that fixes the problem of the circular image resizing to the blurredPic bounds...this might be a question for another topic but now the actual image does not resize to fill the circle... I tried switching .ScaleAspectFit to .ScaleAspectFill and some other ones but no luck...any suggestions? thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of matching centers have you tried using the CGRectInset() function? That way you can assign the frame of the parent UIImageView to the child one, insetted by x,y points, and you wont need to worry about centering it at all.